# How to catch exception from UserNamePasswordValidator in WCF client application?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I've written simple WCF service using netTcpBinding and security mode="Message" and clientCredentialType="UserName". Everything works fine when I pass valid username and password, session is established the way I wanted.
However when the credentials are wrong exception is thrown though I can't catch it in my client application in try catch block.
Did anyone have the same problem ?
Here is my custom validator...

```
public class UserValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        static int counter = 0;
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            ++counter;            
            Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            if (userName != "test" || password != "test")

                throw new FaultException("Bad username or password");

                //throw new SecurityTokenException();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you throwing the security token exception? That's what it's there for. At that point a message has not be sent and the channel has not be opened, so you can't get a fault back.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code that sets up the channel between the client and server? If so, is the channel failing to be created correctly - as with message security the client and server must perform the hadnshake, both providing their credentials to open a security channel. This must be established before any further communications will be enabled, and the fact that invalid credentials are passed will stop the channel being created I suspect.